# С помощью чего решить задачу по распознаванию органов на УЗИ

Tags: opencv, нейронные-сети, искусственный-интеллект, распознавание-образов

Не так давно решил изучать нейронные сети, еще новичок. Понял, что сетей на самом деле много. Не знаю какую выбрать.

Раньше с помощью OpenCV работал со снимками УЗИ, с помощью фильтров выделял контуры органов, но проблема была в том, что руками приходилось подбирать параметры для фильтров, что было не удобно.

[image: узи с выделенным контуром]

Сейчас хочу реализовать программу, чтобы контуры органов определяла сеть. Подскажите, при помощи каких инструментов можно реализовать?

Comment: Отрисовка примерных органов по начальным параметрам в 3D, потом какое-то преобразование как будет выглядеть на УЗИ и подбор параметров органов многомерным поиском. Вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы хотите решать задачу именно с помощью нейронных сетей, то одним из распространенных вариантов являются Fully Convolutional neural networks. К примеру:

https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jonlong/long_shelhamer_fcn.pdf

С точки зрения конкретного инструментария, то практически любой современный фреймворк (TensorFlow, Torch, MXNet, Caffe, etc..) и даже высокоуровные wrapper'ы вроде Keras без проблем справятся с реализацией такого рода сетей.